# Carousel with images and videos

Tags: flutter, image, video, gridview, carousel

I have a general question.

I would like a gridView (**images and videos**) and if you click on the individual image or video, then Open SlideCarousel.

I would get the data from a list that is created from the iphone gallery.

How can I do that.

who has ideas?
who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can find and use easily carousel_slider widget. Click the below link.

[Carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)

Comment: even if images and videos are mixed?

Comment: Please check [link](https://usedpaper.tistory.com/60).
There is method for YouTube video carousel slider. I am not sure mixed for images and videos.